# Flask: RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm trying to control a robot with ROS and flask. The problem is that when i kill ROS with ctrl-c (SIGINT) flask is slowing this process down because it is not closing right away. I have implemented a signal_handler to handle the ctrl-c and close flask.

The problem is that when i run this and press

ctrl-c i closes everything right away but i get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

How can i fix this error?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from raspimouse_ros.msg import MotorFreqs
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, request
from os.path import join, dirname
from signal import signal, SIGINT

cwd = dirname(__file__)
open(join(cwd, "file.html"))

app = Flask(__name__)

deltaX = 0
deltaY = 0

pub = rospy.Publisher('/motor_raw', MotorFreqs, queue_size=10)
rospy.init_node('control')

msg = MotorFreqs()

def signal_handler(signal_received, frame):
    msg.left = 0
    msg.right = 0
    pub.publish(msg)
    print("Quitting .......")
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    func()

signal(SIGINT,signal_handler)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    with open(join(cwd, "file.html"), 'r') as f:
        program = f.read()
    return program

@app.route("/SetSpeed")
def SetSpeed():
    global deltaX
    global deltaY
    deltaX = int(float(request.args.get('x')) * 4)
    deltaY = int(float(request.args.get('y')) * 10)
    publisher()
    return ""

def publisher():
    msg.left = int(-deltaY+deltaX)
    msg.right = int(-deltaY-deltaX)
    rospy.loginfo(msg)
    pub.publish(msg) 

app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

```
[control-1] killing on exit
Quitting .......
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/workspace/src/manual_control/scripts/control.py", line 54, in <module>
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 708, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 673, in inner
    srv.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 511, in serve_forever
    HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 231, in serve_forever
    poll_interval)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 150, in _eintr_retry
    return func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/workspace/src/manual_control/scripts/control.py", line 28, in signal_handler
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The request context is active when a request arrives and is destroyed after it finishes, so it is not availale in the `signal_handler` function, you can, however, access `app_context`.

Comment: So how can i fix this problem?